# Running dojo dgrid : subrows is undefined

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have tried implementing a class for a grid layout using dgrid (using their sample), but I get this error when loading my grid (*subRows is undefined*). My code looks something like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dgrid/Grid",
    "dgrid/Keyboard", 
    "dgrid/Selection"
], function(
    declare,
    lang,
    Grid,
    Keyboard, 
    Selection
){

    return declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection], {

            columns: {
                first: "First Name",
                last: "Last Name",
                age: "Age"
            },
            selectionMode: "single", // for Selection; only select a single row at a time
            cellNavigation: false, // for Keyboard; allow only row-level keyboard navigation

         constructor: function() {
              var data = [
            { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
            { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
            { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
            ];

            this.renderArray(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And calling/creating it like this,

```
app.gridLayout = new GridLayout().placeAt(document.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `constructor` code into `postCreate` method:

```
return declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection], {

    columns: {
        first: "First Name",
        last: "Last Name",
        age: "Age"
    },

    selectionMode: "single",
    cellNavigation: false,

    postCreate: function() {
        var data = [
            { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89},
            { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55},
            { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65}
        ];

        this.renderArray(data);
    }
});
```

Also note `dgrid` is not *dijit* to minimize its dependencies and therefore it has not `placeAt()` method. You have two options here:

1. Provide *DOM node* or `id` *string* of a placeholder to the contructor as a 2nd parameter:

   ```
   var gridLayout = new GridLayout({}, "placeholder");
   ```
2. Make `dgrid` to be a *dijit* via subclassing `dijit/_WidgetBase` to use `gridLayout.placeAt("placeholder")`:

   ```
   declare([_WidgetBase, Grid, Keyboard, Selection], {});
   ```

Comment: what is the difference between a constructor and a postCreate method... and even postMixInPropertie. Looks like (from what I have read), postCreate handles the "last minute" changes on a widget, a constructor gets/sets attributes/parameters (so most of the time using mixin). What about postMixInPropertie? Set again last minute change properties on the widget before rendering..? I'm kind of confuse.

Comment: How does dgrid handle stores (for example json). I tried something with JsonRest and ObjectStore, but I'm kind of confuse on what this.renderArray() does for store (looking at documentation)... I bet I can just scracth that.